# How to speed/parallelize this calculation on the GPU using Torch?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, parallel-processing, pytorch, jit

I am currently stuck on the timewise optimization of my simulator. It took at the begining over 30 hours for one run and is now down to approximate 7 minutes. I have opitmized most of the parts, and the major time decrease was achieved by using torch tensors and assigning the caclulation to the GPU instead of using numpy. However, I know that it should be possible to decrease the runtime down to seconds for a run (assuming that the autors of scientific papers are telling the truth about their simulators).
The following calculation takes most of the time for the calculation and needs to be executed for 3 (cyclic permutation of xl,yl,zl) different scenarios.
Are there any suggestions how to run this on a GPU even faster?
Here is the code with the same dimension. dist and characteristics are dependent on the data and usually not just Tensors filled with ones, but that shouldnt matter here.
Thanks in advance.

```
device = torch.device("cuda")
gp = 995
sp = 200
xl = torch.linspace(-gp, gp, sp).to(device)
yl = torch.linspace(-gp, gp, sp).to(device)
zl = torch.linspace(-1000, 1000, 2).to(device)
factor = 1.5
points = 8000000
dist = torch.ones(points ,3).to(device)
characteristic = torch.ones(points, 1).to(device)

face_dict = {}


for z in zl:
    data = []
    for x_p in xl:
        for y_p in yl:
            dif = dist - torch.Tensor([x_p, y_p, z]).to(device)
            norm = torch.norm(dif, p=2, dim=1).reshape(points, 1)
            limit = factor * (characteristic/ (norm**3) * dif)
            data.append(torch.norm(torch.sum(limit , dim=0)))
    if torch.sign(z) == -1:
        vz = -1
    else:
        vz = 1
    face_dict["(x_y)_(z=" + str(vz) + ")"] = data
```

I already tried from numba import jit, than changed the looop to a function where i insert the torch.Tensor([x_p, y_p, z]).to(device) as a previously created tensor with the corresponding entries. But the result was way slower then before. Also the backend option didnt work.